# how to fix iterating through this arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm using two buttons to iterate back and forth in an arraylist that contains 12 months, when i reach the last element and press the prevButton the app crashes, this also happens when i go back to the first element and hit the nextButton, how do i fix my if statment?

I have tried to do it with >= and <= but it didn't work

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (i < months.size()) {
                    Month month = months.get(i);
                    monthTextView.setText("" + month);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        });


        prevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (i >= 0) {
                    Month month = months.get(i);
                    monthTextView.setText("" + month);
                    i--;
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: the main problem is that you are getting the value before changing `i` - so to say, `i` is pointing to the next value - do as 'm.antkowicz' wrote **and** increment/decrement **before** getting the `month` - and a little note: adding `month` to an empty string is a bit weird, use `...setText(month.toString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the last click you are changing the `i` value anyway to `-1` or `months.size()` by adding/subtracting `1` after accessing last/first element

let us take a look closer on this fragment:

```
if (i >= 0) { // let us assume that i = 0, we are getting inside
    Month month = months.get(i); // you are assigning first element of months, everything is fine
    monthTextView.setText("" + month); // some data operation - irrelevant
    i--; // anyway you are updating i to [i = -1]
}

// one "next" click later...

if (i < months.size()) { // condition is fine because i = -1
    Month month = months.get(i); // oooops tried to access months[-1] - ERROR
    monthTextView.setText("" + month);
    i++;
}
```

The same is happening in the second scenario

What you should do - you should update `i` value only if current value is strongly `> 0` or `< month.size() - 1`

```
if (i >= 0) {
    Month month = months.get(i);
    monthTextView.setText("" + month);
    i = (i > 0) ? (i - 1) : 0; // for example like this
}
```

Comment: I would suggest it is cleaner to always update `i`, but as the first operation within the if statement, and change the bound checks. Otherwise the view will take two taps to update correctly

Comment: basically you are right, however the question is how OP wants his 'list' to be handled after accessing the last/first element. Should it repeatedly show first/last item, do nothing, go to the last/first element like in carousel etc

Comment: agreed with @Michael - it is like if the index is already zero (prev button), do nothing; or already at end (next), do nothing; and it also means that `i` is always pointing to the actual value

Comment: With the current implementation, when you first click next/prev then nothing will happen, assuming that the initial value of `i` used to populate the text view (as we will repopulate with the data for the current value of `i`, and then update `i`).

Comment: thinking of it, strange behavior using that code - e.g. `i == 0`; press `next` and see January; press `next` and see February; press `prev` and see March ??!! and no matter if `next` or `prev` we'll get February

Answer (score 1):

when you reach the last or first index the final value will be `-1` or `maxsize` of it but when you click the opposite button back the condition is still pass, for example when you already at `-1` the next button condition still pass since `-1` is < than `month.size()` your condition should be something like if i-1 <= 0 and then set i

Edit: I think the person who posted this means that when ( i == months.size() - 1 )
and you say next button, it works fine right then because it gets the last month but then i increases by one, that is, i == months.size() is true now. Then, when you press the prevButton, it is only checked if i >= 0 and not i < months.size(). Thus, the array index is out of bounds now. You should check the index bounds in both button methods.

Comment: if i - 1 == 0 then he just do his own logic and then set i-- the same logic still apply he still see the first and the last month